# Multiple Pojos same table Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping, pojo

I have a table that is something like this:

```
╔════════════╗
║ table_test ║
╠════════════╣
║ id         ║
║ type       ║
║ message    ║
║ param_x    ║
║ param_y    ║
║ param_z    ║
║ result_a   ║
║ result_b   ║
║ result_c   ║
╚════════════╝
```

So it's a test that have some parameters and have some results. I don't have a table with the parameters because they aren't pre-defined.

So I want to map this to 3 classes: Test, Paramters and Results.

How can I map this in Hibernate? How Could I, for example, Get the Test and have a Parameters object with the database info ?

Patameters and Result will be fields of Test class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an entity class (Test) and two embedded object classes (Parameters and Results), as described in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-component)

```
@Entity
public class Test
    @Embedded
    private Parameters parameters;

    @Embedded
    private Results results;
}

@Embeddable
public class Parameters {
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class Results {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map them as embedded objects, see [5.1.5. Embedded objects (aka components)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component).